# calculate total value and get percentage value of each using that total value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get percentage for each values.
Input:

```
ShowList = [{
        age: {
            age_55_above: 285737,
            age_25_34: 12217710,
            age_unspecified: 655187,
            age_18_24: 9035930,
            age_45_54: 927554,
            …
        }
        gender: {
            male: 12467636,
            unspecified: 11872,
            female: 17833279
        }
    },
    {
        age: {
            age_55_above: 285237,
            age_25_34: 12227710,
            age_unspecified: 651187,
            age_18_24: 9135930,
            age_45_54: 9227554,
            …
        }
        gender: {
            male: 111467636,
            unspecified: 13872,
            female: 178344279
        }
    }
]
```

1. Add total of age 285737 + 12217710 + 655187 + 9035930 + 927554 and gender 12467636 + 11872 + 17833279.
2. After getting total find percentage for each . ie (285737 / total val //23122118) * 100
3. Output can have the same json format :

```
[{
        age: {
            age_55_above: % val,
            age_25_34:  % val,
            age_unspecified:  % val,
            age_18_24:  % val,
            age_45_54:  % val,
            …
        }
        gender: {
            male:  % val,
            unspecified:  % val,
            female:  % val
        }
    },
    {
        age: {
            age_55_above:  % val,
            age_25_34:  % val,
            age_unspecified:  % val,
            age_18_24:  % val,
            age_45_54:  % val,
            …
        }
        gender: {
            male:  % val,
            unspecified:  % val,
            female:  % val
        }
    }
]
```

What I have tried :
First I am trying to get total and then take out percentage from each value. Any solution is welcome.

```
for (var key in this.ShowsList) {
          for (var keyGender in this.ShowsList[key]) {
              total[key] = {};
              for (var keyVal in this.ShowsList[key][keyGender]) {
                total[key] = total[key] || {};
                total[key]["gender"] = total[key]["gender"] || 0;
                total[key]["age"] = total[key]["age"] || 0;
                if(this.ShowsList[key]["gender"][keyVal] != undefined){
                  total[key]["gender"] += this.ShowsList[key]["gender"][keyVal];
                }
                if(this.ShowsList[key]["age"][keyVal] != undefined){
                  total[key]["age"] += this.ShowsList[key]["age"][keyVal];
                }
                Obj[key] = Obj[key] || {};
                Obj[key][keyGender] = Obj[key][keyGender] || {};
                Obj[key][keyGender][keyVal] = Obj[key][keyGender][keyVal] || 0;
                // Logic to calculate percentage

                // Obj[key]["gender"][keyVal] = ((this.ShowsList[key]["gender"][keyVal]/ total[key]["gender"]) * 100);
// Obj[key]["age"][keyVal] = ((this.ShowsList[key]["age"][keyVal]/ total[key]["gender"]) * 100);

              }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Does the structure of `ShowList`  objects always the same? Will it always have only `age` and `gender` properties?

Comment: Yes @CalvinNunes . It will always have age and gender properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since the `ShowList` inner objects will always have the same structure, you can use the code below. (If for some reason you need scalability or the properties change, then Nina Scholz answer can suit better)

First, start looping through `ShowList`, get each object. 
Then, create an array with only the values of `age` and `gender` of each object, by using `Object.values()`.
Use `.reduce` to sum all those values and get the total for age and gender.
Now, loop each property of `age` and `gender` objects and make the calculation to get %

```js
let ShowList = [{
        age: {
            age_55_above: 285737,
            age_25_34: 12217710,
            age_unspecified: 655187,
            age_18_24: 9035930,
            age_45_54: 927554            
        },
        gender: {
            male: 12467636,
            unspecified: 11872,
            female: 17833279
        }
    },
    {
        age: {
            age_55_above: 285237,
            age_25_34: 12227710,
            age_unspecified: 651187,
            age_18_24: 9135930,
            age_45_54: 9227554,            
        },
        gender: {
            male: 111467636,
            unspecified: 13872,
            female: 178344279
        }
    }
]

var results = []

for (var i = 0; i < ShowList.length; i++){
  let currentObj = ShowList[i];
  
  let ageValues = Array.from(Object.values(currentObj.age))
  let genderValues = Array.from(Object.values(currentObj.gender))
  
  let totalAges = ageValues.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
  let totalGender = genderValues.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
  
  let newObj = {age: {}, gender: {}}
  
  for (let key in currentObj.age){
    newObj.age[key] = (currentObj.age[key] / totalAges) * 100 + " %"
  }
  
  for (let key in currentObj.gender){
    newObj.gender[key] = (currentObj.gender[key] / totalGender) * 100 + " %"
  }
  
  results.push(newObj)
}

console.log(results)
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, is it possible to make some changes in my code and get it working

Answer (score 3):

You could take a complete dynamic approach and get the percent values by adding the items and return the parts.

```js
function getPercent(object) {
    var entries = Object.entries(object),
        sum = entries.reduce((s, { 1: v }) => s + v, 0);

    return Object.assign({}, ...entries.map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v * 100 / sum })));
}

var data = [{ age: { age_55_above: 285737, age_25_34: 12217710, age_unspecified: 655187, age_18_24: 9035930, age_45_54: 927554 }, gender: { male: 12467636, unspecified: 11872, female: 17833279 } }, { age: { age_55_above: 285237, age_25_34: 12227710, age_unspecified: 651187, age_18_24: 9135930, age_45_54: 9227554 }, gender: { male: 111467636, unspecified: 13872, female: 178344279 } }],
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign(
        {},
        ...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: getPercent(v) }))
    ));

   console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at here:-

```js
let ShowList = [
  {
    "age": {
      "age_55_above": 285737,
      "age_25_34": 12217710,
      "age_unspecified": 655187,
      "age_18_24": 9035930,
      "age_45_54": 927554
    },
    "gender": {
      "male": 12467636,
      "unspecified": 11872,
      "female": 17833279
    }
  },
  {
    "age": {
      "age_55_above": 285237,
      "age_25_34": 12227710,
      "age_unspecified": 651187,
      "age_18_24": 9135930,
      "age_45_54": 9227554
    },
    "gender": {
      "male": 111467636,
      "unspecified": 13872,
      "female": 178344279
    }
  }
]

let result = ShowList.map(function(item){
        let o = {};
        for(let key in item){// top level iteration
          o[key] = {}
          let sum = Object.keys(item[key]).reduce((a,b)=> a+item[key][b], 0) 
          for(let subkey in item[key]){// sub level iteration
            o[key][subkey] = (item[key][subkey]/sum)*100;
          }
        }
        return o;
      })


console.log(result)
```